# How to get value from another cy function in Cypress

Tags: variables, cypress

I want to display value from another cy function in cypress. but when I tried, it's always empty/blank

here's my code

```
var nil
    cy.get('#email_create')
        .then((nilai) => {
            var nil = nilai.val()
        })
    cy.log(nil)
```

my question is, how to display the `nil` variable in another `cy` function

thank you so much

Comment: They are not functions, they are commands. Unfortunately some expected javascript patterns do not work in a Cypress test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's happening because cypress is async.  `cy.log(nil)` is happening before `var nil = nilai.val()`.

Try this:

```
    cy.get('#email_create')
        .then((nilai) => {
            var nil = nilai.val()
            cy.log(nil)
        })
```